# Can you get a Schengen visa with a different passport when you lose one?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, passports, europe

I have two passports. I entered Spain with the first one, because it had the Schengen long-term visa and I lost it. Can I get a visa on the other one? I read that I may have some troubles when I exit the country.

Answer (score 1):

You should report the loss of the passport and visa to the police, to the nearest consulate or embassy of the country that issued the passport, and to the Spanish immigration authorities.  They will be able to tell you how to replace your lost visa.

Comment: but my question is, can I get the visa on the other passport that I have? because I have two nationalities

Comment: @AshrafTaha maybe.  You can ask the immigration authorities whether they will issue the visa in your other passport.  Another option is to replace the passport that was lost and get the visa issued in that passport, which is what anyone who had only one passport to start with would have to do.

Comment: @AshrafTana it's also possible that they will issue a residence card instead of a visa, since many countries will only issue visas abroad.  In that case, they may issue a separate document rather than putting a sticker in your passport.